# invalid conversion of a char* to int

Tags: c++

I am stuck on this part and i need help regarding fixing compilation errors in the below code. I am a using g++ compiler.

The error message is as follows : " invalid conversion from âconst char*â to âintâ [-fpermissive] "

```
bool isRegistered(const Prefix* pre,int area,const char* publisher, int * pos)
{
int n,i=0,num,flag=0,low,high,pub;
n=*(pos);
while(pre->area[n]==area)
{
num=publisher[i]-48;

switch(pre->pubLen[n])
{
case 1:

num=publisher[i]-48;
```

> The problem is down below in every case .

```
low=((*pre).pubLow[n])-48;
high=(pre->pubHigh[n])-48; 
if((num>low)&&(num<high))
{
pub=num;
}
break;

case 2:
num=(publisher[i]-48)*10+(publisher[i+1]-48);
low=(pre->pubLow[n])-48;
high=(pre->pubHigh[n])-48;
if((num>low)&&(num<high))
{
pub=num;
}
break;
```

> Definition of Prefix

```
struct Prefix {
    int  no;             // number of entries
    int  area[MAX];      // area elements
    char pubLow[MAX][8]; // low end of publisher range
    char pubHigh[MAX][8]; // high end of publisher range
    int  pubLen[MAX];    // no of chars in publisher string
};
```

> Case 3 and so on ....

Comment: Can you show the line that gave the error?

Comment: You need help writing the code, not debugging it

Comment: These two lines are giving the error .

low=((*pre).pubLow[n])-48;

high=(pre->pubLow[n])-48;

Comment: What's the definition of the type `Prefix`?

Comment: Considering we have no clue what type `pubLow` is, we can't help.

Comment: struct Prefix {
    int  no;             // number of entries
    int  area[MAX];      // area elements
    char pubLow[MAX][8]; // low end of publisher range
    char pubHgh[MAX][8]; // high end of publisher range
    int  pubLen[MAX];    // no of chars in publisher string
};

Comment: Yeah, so `pubLow[x]` gives you a `char[8]`, which you try to subtract 48 from, resulting in undefined behaviour, and then try to store the pointer result in an integer.

Comment: okhay, actually i am pretty new to c++a and i am all confused . i actually want to put the ascii value of a character to an int and then subtract 48 from it to get the exact numeric value .

Comment: This isn't 'debugging', it is 'fixing compile errors'.

Comment: Thank you for that information, but that still doesn't solves my problem.

Comment: That's why it was posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @LuvKapur if you want to convert a char buffer / std::string to an int, you should be using a function like [atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) / [strtoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). C++ is a statically-typed language, not a dynamic one. You can't just cast between unrelated types and expect to get a correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Give the definition of `pubLow`

Also

```
**low=((*pre).pubLow[n])-48;
high=(pre->pubLow[n])-48; **
```

low is an integer, remove `**` before low and after `48;` 
Such that it becomes

```
low=((*pre).pubLow[n])-48;
high=(pre->pubLow[n])-48;
```

**Here is your code**

```
 bool isRegistered(const Prefix* pre,int area, char* publisher, int * pos)
{
int n,i=0,num,flag=0,low,high,pub;
n=*(pos);
while(pre->area[n]==area)
{
num=publisher[i]-48;

switch(pre->pubLen[n])
{
case 1:

num=publisher[i]-48;
    low=atoi(((*pre).pubLow[n])-48);
high=atoi((pre->pubHigh[n])-48); 
if((num>low)&&(num<high))
{
pub=num;
}
break;

case 2:
num=(((publisher[i]-48)*10)+(publisher[i+1]-48));
low=atoi((pre->pubLow[n])-48);
high=atoi((pre->pubHigh[n])-48);
if((num>low)&&(num<high))
{
pub=num;
}
break;
```